# C calling Assembly Link Issue

Tags: c, gcc, assembly

So I've been trying to link a c program and an assembly program using the code

```
gcc -o test_asm add.o main.o
```

But it always gives me the error:

> C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
>   i386 architecture of input file `add.o' is incompatible with
>   i386:x86-64 output

I have tried using -m32 to compile my C program as well but it still gives me the same problem and doesn't output an exe file. What is the way to fix this issue, any help would be appreciated.

I used `nasm -f elf -o add.o add.asm` for my assembly file

and `gcc -m32 -c main.c main.o` for my c program.

Comment: Show us the command lines that generated the .o files.

Comment: what is `count.o` when you don't even have it in the `gcc` command? Did you compile your _NASM_ code with `-f elf` or `-f elf32`? If so you'd need to use `-f elf64`. The error suggests you are mixing 32-bit and 64-bit objects and trying to produce a 64-bit executable. You need to make sure all the objects are 64-bit or all are 32-bit. Since you don't show code I don't know what type of executable you are creating.

Comment: Sorry, count.o was from a different try. I have edited the post to show the right codes. I will try using -f elf64 now, hopefully it works.

Comment: well now it appears you are trying to create a 32-bit program since you created objects that were 32-bit. Problem is that your final command `gcc -o test_asm add.o main.o` tries to generate a 64-bit executable. How about `gcc -m32 -o test_asm add.o main.o` . If you want a 32-bit program you need to use `f elf` (or `-f elf32`) on each NASM line and `-m32` on each GCC command.

Comment: I told you... on that other site. ;-)